# How to efficiently evaluate only parts of an n dimensional function

Tags: performance-tuning

Suppose I have a costy n dimensional function:

$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$

like one of these two:

```
f[t_] = Array[BesselJZero[#1, #1*t] &, {150}];
g[t_] = Array[Nest[Sin, #*t, 100] &, {15000}];
```

I would like to evaluate only a part of them (lets say the first entry) as fast as possible. The naive way would be:

**Code 1:**

```
AbsoluteTiming[f[1.][[1]]]
AbsoluteTiming[g[1.][[1]]]
```

> {0.617862, 3.83171}
>
> {0.724064, 0.168852}

This is super slow since Mathematica calculates all entries and then takes the first value of it. So I tried something like:

**Code 2**

```
AbsoluteTiming[f[t][[1]] /. t -> 1.]
AbsoluteTiming[(g[t][[1]]) /. t -> 1.]
```

> {0.0078714, 3.83171}
>
> {0.591159, 0.168852}

This approach is fine for the function `f` because `BesselJZero` is a costy function itself but not hard to construct explicitly. What I don't quite get is why this approach is still slow for g.
What I came up at the end and what seems to work is something like this:

**Code 3**

```
g2 = g[t];
f2 = f[t];
AbsoluteTiming[f2[[1]] /. t -> 1.]
AbsoluteTiming[g2[[1]] /. t -> 1.]
```

> {0.0122119, 3.83171}
>
> {0.000198283, 0.168852}

I would like to know:

- Whats the convenient way to deal with high dimensional functions and evaluating only parts of it?
- Why is `g` not sped up in Code 2? Its explicit form was already created by `Set` in the definition wasn't it? I would understand this if I used `Unset` but I didn't.
- How would you evaluate the first entry of `f` and `g` efficiently if they were interpolating functions?

**Edit:** To question 3 an example:

```
h = Interpolation[Table[{t, Array[Sin[#1 t] Cos[#2 t] &, {150, 150}]}, {t,0.5,1.5,.01}]];
AbsoluteTiming[h[1.][[1, 1]]]
AbsoluteTiming[Sin[1*#] Cos[1*#] &[1.]]
```

> {0.0324101, 0.454649}
>
> {0.0000106736, 0.454649}

Here I would like Mathematica to skip evaluating the whole function `h`, just the value 1,1 should be computed. The speed should be in the order of the second value. I have no equivalent here trying to extract the 1,1 component in beforehand as I did before with `f` and `g`.

Comment: Evaluating `g[t]` is what takes the time. In Code 3 your evaluation of `g[t]` happens outside of the `AbsoluteTiming`. As for your last question, what is an example using interpolating functions?

Comment: Isn't the *construction* of `g` done when I define `g` via `Set`? And shouldn't then the *explicite symbolic expression* be saved in `g`?
I added an example interpolating function `h` to the question.

Comment: I wonder if using `Inactive`  in the definition of the function would help here?  Select the part you want and then `Activate` the expression

Comment: Can you express your function as a Series and retain just the first few (dominating) terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the difference between your "Code 2" and "Code 3" timing is that "Code 3" doesn't include the timing to evaluate `g[t]`:

```
g2 = g[t]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.456115, Null}

As for your question on interpolating functions, one idea is to modify the interpolating function before using it. Here is a function that modifies the interpolating function:

```
ifpart[h_, part__] := Module[{if=h},
    if[[4]] = h[[4, All, All, part]];
    if
]
```

Compare:

```
h[1.001][[2,3]] //RepeatedTiming
hp = ifpart[h, 2, 3]; //RepeatedTiming
hp[1.001] //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.020, -0.89973}
>
> {0.0000126, Null}
>
> {3.0*10^-6, -0.89973}

Comment: The nested List of `g` needs time to construct. I thought `Set` is only constructing this once while `Unset` constructs it for every call. And indeed when using `Set` the definition of `g` needs some time. When calling `g[1.]` then, I thought the evaluation of `Nest` and `Array` would not be needed anymore but it doesnt seem like it. Only when defining another explicite variable `g2` really evaluates `Nest` and `Array` and *saves the result as symbolic expression* for later use. Dont understand why `Set` is not doing that in the first place. Thats what I meant in the comments earlier.